# Where is the Image class in C#?

Tags: c#, bitmap

I am simply trying to encode and decode bitmap images, but the Image class apparently doesn't exist. I am going off the [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-encode-and-decode-a-bmp-image) to create a decoder. I am getting an error at

`Image drawnImg = new Image();`

It says, *"the type or namespace could not be found"*, and every import I use is not fixing this error. What library am I missing here?

Here is code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Remoting.Metadata.W3cXsd2001;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Thompson_BmpDecodeEncode
{
    class Thompson_BmpDecodeEndoce
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Uri img = new Uri("<FilePath to image.bmp>", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute);
            BmpBitmapDecoder decoder2 = new BmpBitmapDecoder(img, 
                BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
            BitmapSource bitmapSource2 = decoder2.Frames[0];

            Image drawnImg = new Image();

            Console.ReadKey();
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried going to your favorite search engine and typing `c# image class`? Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Click on Project --> Add Reference, then select Framework on the left.  On the right find System.Drawing and put a checkmark next to it.  Click OK.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One thing I like to do when I can't find a library is open my favorite search engine and search for it (adding c# doesn't hurt, either).

The top result when searching for *"c# image class"* is: [Image Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1), where it states:

Namespace: 
[System.Drawing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1)

---

Update:

Also, in order to add a `using` statement for a library, you need to first add a reference to that library in your project. To do this in Visual Studio, you can right-click on the `References` node under the project in the `Solution Explorer`, and then under `Assemblies -> Framework`, you can check the box next to `System.Drawing`:

[image]

If you're not using visual studio, you can edit your `.csproj` file with the reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="" DefaultTargets="" xmlns="">
  <ItemGroup>
    <Reference Include="System.Drawing" />
```

Comment: I searched it before I asked this. I tried this, and it gives me the same error. All my refactorings are suggesting using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames; Which I am unsure if this is the correct object to work with.

Comment: I don't see `using System.Drawing;` in your code sample. What do you mean by *"I tried this, and it gives me the same error"*. What specifically did you try, and what specifically is the error?

Comment: I removed it because it didn't work. I will add it back.

Comment: @Zthom don't forget you might have to add a reference to the DLL before being able to use the namespace

Comment: What do you mean by "it didn't work"? Please include any error messages you get (and also include how you're adding a reference to that library for your project, which is required before adding the `using` statement)

Comment: I got the same error: 
Error CS0246 The type or namespace name 'Image' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: If you're not missing the using directive, then you must be missing the assembly reference. I've updated the answer with more details.

Comment: I may have done an incorrect import, but now it thinks the Image class is an abstract? I get the error: 
Error CS0144 Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'Image' Am I calling the constructor wrong?

Comment: Oh, my bad - i didn't realize you were using WPF. At the bottom of [the paged you linked](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/how-to-encode-and-decode-a-bmp-image), there is a section that says, "See also: [Imaging Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/graphics-multimedia/imaging-overview), and on that page it states, *"Image resides in the System.Windows.Controls namespace."*

Comment: That gives me the error Controls does not exist, and when I look in the references, it is not in there too. I am very new to C#. I apologize if this is extraneous, but I am trying to learn.    :(

Error CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Controls' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you doing this in a `WPF` project? There should be a reference to `System.Windows` there already, and you can just add `using System.Windows.Conrtrols` without any additional library references, and then `Image` will be available in your code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215340/discussion-between-zthom-and-rufus-l).